# Написать SQL-запрос, который вернёт имена топ 10 авторов отзывов, комментарии под которыми собрали наибольшее количество лайков

Tags: sql

У вас есть две таблицы: review и user.

Таблица review:

- id: уникальный идентификатор отзыва/комментария.
- user_id:идентификатор автора отзыва/комментария.
- content: содержание отзыва/комментария.
- likes_count: количество лайков у
  отзыва/комментария.
- dislikes_count: количество дизлайков у
  отзыва/комментария.
- parent_id: если значение не null, это
  комментарий, и значение указывает на идентификатор родительского
  отзыва.
- item_name: название товара, на который оставлен
  отзыв/комментарий. created_at: дата создания записи.

Таблица user:

- id: уникальный идентификатор пользователя.
- name: имя пользователя.

Мне необходимо написать SQL-запрос, который вернёт имена топ 10 авторов отзывов, комментарии под которыми собрали наибольшее количество лайков (без учёта дизлайков), и сумму лайков на комментариях под отзывами автора.
Результат должен содержать 2 колонки в следующем порядке:

name: содержит имя автора отзывов
total_likes: содержит сумму лайков на комментариях под отзывами автора

Я написал вот такой запрос, но он не проходит тест. Помогите его исправить

```
SELECT user.name AS name, SUM(r.likes_count) AS total_likes FROM review r
JOIN user ON r.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN review ON review.parent_id = r.id
WHERE review.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY r.parent_id, r.id, r.user_id, r.content, r.likes_count, r.dislikes_count, r.item_name, r.created_at
ORDER BY total_likes DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: А зачем же потребовалось напихивать столько всего в выражение группировки? И зачем потребовалось внешнее связывание? И главное - считать-то надо лайки не у отзывов, а у комментариев, для получения которых нужна ещё одна копия таблицы отзывов. И вообще - в текущем виде запрос пытается получить данные для юзеров, не написавших ни одного отзыва либо комментария.

Comment: вам бы надо сначала посчитать отзывы и суммарное количество лайков к ним. Далее надо понять, что топ 10 постов по лайкам и топ 10 авторов это разные вещи. Так что тут надо отранжировать по автору и отобрать топ.

Comment: хотя, если там суммарно лайки нужны по всем вообще постам автора, то ранжировать не надо.

Comment: @Akina сори, я экспериментировал. Такой запрос сработал на экспериментальной таблице, которую я создал, но не могу понять, как его улучшить, чтобы он проходил в тесте

Comment: Такое решение подойдет? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/25d1a/1
для тестов не стал заводить лишние поля, которые не используются.

Comment: @ДмитрийБесшапошников, к сожалению возвращается вот такая ошибка
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nulls last 
LIMIT 10' at line 10

Answer (score 0):

Такое решение подойдет? [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/25d1a/9) для тестов не стал заводить лишние поля, которые не используются.
В предыдущем решении вы получили ошибку check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nulls last LIMIT 10' at line 10, это значит, что у вас неподдерживается конструкция nulls last, здесь я ее убрал

```
SELECT 
  u.name AS name
  , SUM(r1.likes_count) AS total_likes 
FROM  user_table u
JOIN review r
  ON r.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN review r1 
  ON r1.parent_id = r.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
having SUM(r1.likes_count) is not null
ORDER BY total_likes DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Этот код выводит имена и полученные лайки и порядке убывания, но по непонятным для меня причинам автотест проваливается и выводит ошибку. К сожалению, не могу пока отметить это решение, как верное((

Comment: а какую ошибку выдает? 
вам так и нужно вывести имена в порядке убывания, или нужно выводить именно авторов, у которых сумма лайков на комментарии к одному посту максимальная?

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю почему в http://sqlfiddle.com/ выводит всё нормально, а на степике вот так:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfCHI.jpg

Comment: Необходимо написать SQL-запрос, который вернёт имена топ 10 авторов отзывов, комментарии под которыми собрали наибольшее количество лайков (без учёта дизлайков), и сумму лайков на комментариях под отзывами автора.
Результат должен содержать 2 колонки в следующем порядке:

name: содержит имя автора отзывов
total_likes: содержит сумму лайков на комментариях под отзывами автора